# Find and replace string in directory names

Tags: find, rename

I have a file structure that I had to recover and it contains :2f in the name

For example directory name `anyname:2fmorename`

I want to be able to change `:2f` to `_` in all directories and sub directories.

I thinking something like

```
find . -name *:2f* -type d -execdir mv{} *_* \;
```

But I can not figure out for sure.

Comment: be careful if you use `find`, to use `-depth`, or else you may rename a parent directory before finding a child one

Comment: If you ever want to test something like your proposed `find` command, there's nothing stopping you using `echo mv` instead of `mv`.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the Perl `rename` installed you can do it with this:

```
find . -name '*:2f*' -type d -exec rename 's/:2f/_/g' {} \;
```

If you **want to test it first** then add an `echo`:

```
find . -name '*:2f*' -type d -exec echo rename 's/:2f/_/g' {} \;
```

Answer (score 4):

Thanks I ended up getting it to work using the following:

```
find /path -depth -type d -name '*:2f*' -execdir bash -c 'mv -v "$1" "${1//:2f/_}"' _ {} \;
```